# Modify Crystal Enterprise User Access via query

Tags: crystal-reports, business-objects, business-objects-sdk

I'm looking for a way to modify the groups a Crystal Enterprise User is in via query in order to automate some of our tasks.

We currently have anywhere from 5-20 users a day that get added or have their security access change and it would be beneficial if we could automate this.  The main things that would need to be changed are the user description and which groups the user is in.

Is there a way this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the [SAP BUSINESSOBJECTS BI 4.X - DEVELOPER SDK LIBRARY](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-27465) to perform these tasks.  There are earlier verions of the SDK, if you aren't using 4.X.